# How search Engines uniquely identify each pages on web

Tags: web-crawler, search-engine, google-crawlers, search-engine-bots, code-search-engine

If I write a post who's link is 'example.com/abc.php' & this post is ranking in Search Engine.

After some days I update this post including its content & also its permalink to 'xyz.php'.

So now the post which had URL 'example.com/abc.php' before is updated to 'example.com/xyz.php'.

Then how Search Engines will get to know this is the same page/post which is already ranking with URL example.com/abc.php.
And need to update link in search results to 'example.com/xyz.php' without affecting the ranking.

Is there any tag or something needed to write in code while creating a new post which uniquely identity page for Search Engines before & after updating permalink?

Note:-This website is developed by coding,not by using CMS.
Languages used are HTML,CSS,JavaScript and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines uniquely identify web pages with the help of the crawler. There are hundreds of billions of pages crawled using their web crawlers. These are commonly referred to as search engine bots or spiders. A search engine navigates the web URL by downloading web pages and following links on these pages to find new pages that have been made available.